# QuoteName not giving result

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I am trying this code

```
CREATE TABLE #t 
( 
   nam Varchar(100) 
) 
INSERT INTO #t(nam)VALUES('abc[]def') 
SELECT * FROM #t Where Quotename(nam) like Quotename('abc[]def') 
drop table #t
```

and not giving me any result.... Am I missing something?

Comment: Don't use `LIKE` when you know the exact string. `SELECT * FROM #t Where nam = 'abc[]def'` works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE #t 
( 
   nam Varchar(100) 
); 
INSERT INTO #t(nam)VALUES('abc[]def'); 
SELECT * FROM #t Where Quotename(nam) = Quotename('abc[]def');
drop table #t;
```

Its not returning anything because Brackets `[ ]` are know as Wildcard alphabets with `LIKE`. 
The set of characters specified between brackets wildcard which will match any one characters in the specified position (the location of the wildcard).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx

Please open the link and search the following text.

**Using the [ ] wildcard characters**

Answer (score 1):

You don't need quotename you need [escape](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx)

```
CREATE TABLE #t 
( 
   nam VARCHAR(100) 
) 
INSERT INTO #t(nam) VALUES('abc[]def') 

SELECT * 
FROM #t 
WHERE nam LIKE 'abc\[]def' ESCAPE '\' 

DROP TABLE #t
```